# Determining Values in Pandas Dataframe Based on Previous Rows Value in Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Name | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-11-01 | Yes |
| Jane | 2022-11-01 | No |
| Emily | 2022-11-02 | No |
| John | 2022-11-02 | No |
| Emily | 2022-11-03 | Yes |
| Jane | 2022-11-03 | No |
| Emily | 2022-11-04 | No |

I want to check and count the names that has `Status` 'Yes' in the order of date. So, if the `Name` has `Status` 'Yes' on the previous date (or rows, since the data is already ordered by ascending date), it will be counted as 1.

I've read about `pandas.dataframe.shift`, `pandas.dataframe.isin`, `pandas.dataframe.equals`, but I don't think that's the function that I want to check the value of previous row.

**The expected output is:**

2     (John, Emily)

Can anyone help me to build the code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: interesting, im guessing you could create another column called something like `status_yesterday` and check whether the status of today is the same as yesterday

Comment: since the `Status` 'Yes' is not always on the previous date, I don't think that solves my problem. But, I'm open to any suggestions! Can you explain more about how to count the `status_yesterday` as my expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby()` -> `transform()` to process block of records grouped by each person. Sort records by date, and check if previous date has status "Yes". Collect all results with positive check flag.

The comments are added before each line to explain the logic.

```py
# For each "Name", check if previous date has status "Yes".
def check_prev_date_status(g):
    df_g = g.apply(pd.Series)

    # Sort by date.
    df_g = df_g.sort_values(0)

    # Check if last but one status is "Yes".
    if df_g[-2:-1][1].values[0] == "Yes":
      return 1
    else:
      return 0

# Compute tuple of "Date" and "Status" for easy processing as one column. It is hard to process multiple columns with "transform()".
df["Date_Status"] = df[["Date", "Status"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)

# Apply above function and compute flag if previous date has status "Yes".
df["check_status_flag"] = df.groupby("Name")[["Date_Status"]].transform(check_prev_date_status)

# Filter and count the results.
print(df[df["check_status_flag"] == 1]["Name"].unique())
```

Output:

```
['John' 'Emily']
```